# ssh hostname.local only works some of the time

Tags: ssh, networking

I'm having this weird issue where ssh to devices using `ssh user@hostname.local` only works sporadically (several machines, all Linux based). Using `ssh user@<ip-address>` always works but it's a bit annoying to use.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: flimsy name resolution. Who's responsible for resolving your .local addresses?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My router is I guess. I had this problem here and in my old place (both with janky network setups). I wouldn't be surprised if it straight up didn't work, but half the time seems weird to me.

Comment: yeah, probably depends on how "fresh" some notion of having a name is in *something*'s cache. You could try `host hostname.local` when it fails to see whether that looks ok. Also, running ssh with -vv might, for a start, confirm what the actual reason of failure is. So far we just know it fails, not even *how* it fails.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for suggesting the -vv option. It shows the device is following the `*` host but trying to connect to an invalid ip that the device used to be on. I haven't been able to figure out where this ip is cached though. `systemctl is-active systemd-resolved.service` returns active, but I can't use the corresponding command. Most other services that I find people suggest work are not found or don't work as stated in the articles.